# Is there a difference in meaning between 'wütend sein' and 'wüten'?

Tags: difference, participle

For example, do

> *Der Chef ist wütend.*

and

> *Der Chef wütet.*

mean the same thing?

I'm asking because the [German for English Speakers](http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/verbs/present-participles-and-gerunds) site says

> The present participle is a way of using a verb as an adjective, and in German it's only used right before a noun, as in "running water" or "barking dogs."

The first sentence above seems to be an exception to this. (There are other exceptions as well; the [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partizip#Eigenschaften_im_Deutschen) has more information. But I think I understand most of them, and I'm trying to limit the question to a single issue.)

PS. So I gather that the reason this is an exception to the rule given above is that the participle's meaning has diverged significantly from the original verb. You can use (present participle) + *sein*, but only if converting it to the simple present tense would change the meaning. Since *wüten*/*wütend sein* is an example where the meaning would change, *wütend sein* is allowed.

I think a similar case is *sich schleppen*/*schleppend sein*. You can say *Der Film ist schleppend* to mean that the movie is slow and boring. But *Der Film schleppt sich* seems to imply some kind of movement, which might be applied figuratively to the plot, but it seems unusual to do apply it to the movie itself.

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/w%C3%BCten

Comment: In the context of the boss, "Wüten" can also refer to them making drastic decisions due to being angry/irritated. 'Wüten' is also used somewhat ambiguously when someone is working intensely or in a way that leaves a lot of disorder. "Er hat in der Küche gewütet" can be used to describe someone cooking in a manner that leaves the kitchen in a messy state.

Comment: @Mookuh: Interesting. With a word like *Wüten* I guess you can expect a whole host of figurative and exaggerated meanings. I'd translated your example as "He ran amok in the kitchen." -- A similar exaggeration.

Comment: No, not only right before a noun, by the way – wherever an adjective or especially adverb is used (*'das Kind lief heulend nach Hause'*, *'der Chef schaute mich lächelnd an'*, ...).

Comment: @Aconcagua: Good examples. This is covered in the Wikipedia article; they have '*Der Mann geht singend durch das Haus*', as an example.

Comment: By the way, for completeness (adopted from comments to the accepted answer): Some equivalence to *English* participle exists as well, but using another construct for: The storm rages -> Der Sturm wütet. The storm *is raging* -> Der Sturm *ist am Wüten*...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, there is a strong difference:

#### Der Chef ist wütend.

This means:

> The boss feels angry.

It expresses just an emotion. It does not need to express any action. The boss can sit quite in his chair, looking nice and friendly, so nobody notices that he feels angry. It's just about the emotion the boss has.

#### Der Chef wütet.

This means:

> The boss rages.

This is about a very emotional action. He shouts load, runs around and throws objects around the room. It is impossible not to notice what he is doing. Everybody can see and hear him destroying furniture and shouting loud.

---

Interesting is this:

> Der wütende Chef (kommt auf mich zu).

This can mean two things:

1. The angry boss (comes towards me.)
2. The raging boss (comes towards me.)

Normally you mean #1: The boss feels angry. But depending on context it also could be #2: The boss is raging.

Comment: Using the phrase "Der Chef ist wütend" is impossible if nobody has noticed that he feels angry. Only a omniscient narrator could say it without having noticed signs of *Wut*.

Comment: Instead of "the chef feels/is angry" you could also say "the chef is enraged". Rage really is a good translation here. It also works for storms; "the storm rages", "der Sturm wütet".

Comment: I would think that today, "wüten" is used mostly with storms, and perhaps troops or other groups that vandalize a place much like a force of nature, but rarely with single persons.

Comment: @Peter - Reinstate Monica: The DWDS usage database is a good test for that and you're right: fires, plagues, storms, a whole litany of disasters.

Comment: It's interesting that since the meanings are so different, the attributive version is now ambiguous. But I suppose that can be fixed by rephrasing the sentence if there is any doubt. I gather that the basic meaning of "wüten" is like you described, but it seems that figurative meanings (for disasters) and hyperbolic meanings (see Paul Frost's answer) are also in common use. I assume you would never say *Der Orkan ist wütend.*

Comment: @KritikerderElche, no problem to use "Der Chef ist wütend" without being omniscient. It's easily possible to tell if someone is angry just by looking at them. Bright red face and neck, pressure-breathing, noticeably high muscle tension etc. All of which can happen without actually raging (i.e., shouting, smashing things etc.).

Comment: @KritikerderElche: Und gemessen daran, wie häufig in fiktionalen Texten der Autor ein allwissender ist, ist das keine relevante Einschränkung.

Comment: @AnoE This is what I said: A bright red face and neck and pressure-breathing is a sign of *Wut*. If you do not notice anything (quotation from the answer "The boss can sit quite in his chair, looking nice and friendly, so nobody notices that he feels angry"), why would you call him *wütend*?

Comment: @userunknown In einem (nicht nur fiktionalen) Text kann der Autor das natürlich so schreiben ohne ausdrücklich auf äußere Anzeichen von Wut einzugehen. Man kann auch einem Kollegen sagen, dass der Chef wütend ist ohne dafür Beweise vorzulegen. Dennoch erfordert die Diagnose von Wut gewisse Symptome. In der Antwort steht  "The boss can sit quite in his chair, looking nice and friendly, so nobody notices that he feels angry." Wer weiß nun, dass er wütend ist?

Comment: This seems like a grammar distinction that exists in other languages (e.g. English), not just German.  Predicate adjective versus intransitive verb.

Comment: Maybe correct s/Intersting/Interesting/; I cannot suggest one-character edits?

Comment: @KritikerderElche: **Erstens:** Wie du selbst ganz richtig erkannt hast, kann ein allwissender Erzähler sehr wohl davon berichten, dass eine Figur einer Erzählung wütend ist, ohne das nach außen hin zu zeigen: *»Erika war sehr wütend als sie erfuhr, dass Martin die Rose, die sie ihm geschenkt hatte, an Ivonne weitergegeben hat. Aber weil niemand in der Runde ahnen durfte, wie sehr sie in Martin verliebt war, verzog Erika trotzdem keine Mine und lächelte weiterhin freundlich.«* **Zweitens:** Dass die Möglichkeit besteht, dass innere Wut mit fehlendem äußeren Eindruck einhergeht, bedeutet ...

Comment: ... ja nicht, dass das der Normalfall ist. Selbstverständlich zeigt sich Wut im Normalfall auch durch äußere Anzeichen. Ich habe ja weder behauptet, dass innere Wut immer ohne äußere Kennzeichen vonstattengeht, noch, dass das häufig geschieht. Ich habe zur Unterscheidung der beiden Begriffe lediglich festgestellt, dass Wütendsein sogar ohne irgendwelchen nach außen sichtbaren Kennzeichen möglich ist, während es unmöglich ist zu wüten ohne dass es anwesende Personen mitbekommen.

Comment: Wut ist ein Gefühl und Gefühle kann man unterdrücken. Wenn man ein Gefühl unterdrückt bedeutet das ja nicht, dass man es nicht hat, sondern nur, dass man es nicht zeigt. Wenn jemand wütet, wird damit hingegen eine ganz bestimmte Handlung beschrieben. Handlungen kann man aber nicht unterdrücken wie Gefühle. Man führt die Handlung aus (dann wütet die Person, was für Anwesende immer wahrnehmbar ist) oder man führt sie nicht aus.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Einigen wir uns auf Folgendes: 1. Man kann von sich selbst sagen, dass man wütend ist oder war, ohne dass es sichtbare Anzeichen gibt oder gab. 2. Man kann über einen anderen Menschen nicht sagen, dass er wütend ist, wenn man keine Anzeichen dafür sieht. 3. Man kann sagen, dass er aufgrund bestimmter Ereignisse *wütend sein sollte* ("Er muss ziemlich wütend gewesen sein, hat es sich aber nicht anmerken lassen"). 4. Der allwissende Erzähler kann alles über eine fiktive Person sagen ohne etwas zu begründen.

Comment: @KritikerderElche selbstverständlich kann man auch über eine andere Person sagen, dass sie wütend ist, ohne es wirklich zu wissen. Grammatik impliziert nicht inhaltliche Korrektheit. Und Dinge als Faktum zu formulieren, obwohl man sie eigentlich nur zu wissen glaubt, kommt extrem häufig vor. Hast Du ja in deinem ersten Kommentar auch so gemacht.

Comment: @Holger Natürlich sind grammatische Korrektheit und inhaltliche Korrektheit zwei verschiedene Dinge. Wenn Du die Antwort und die Kommentare liest, wirst Du aber feststellen, dass sich mein erster Kommentar auf "The boss can sit quite in his chair, looking nice and friendly, so nobody notices that he feels angry" bezieht. Auf welcher Grundlage sollte ein Mitarbeiter hier zum Urteil kommen, dass der Chef wütend ist? Das könnte man dann zu jedem beliebigen Zeitpunkt als "Faktum" formulieren.

Comment: Im Kontrast zum wütend seienden Menschen, der dennoch nicht wütet, steht noch der wütend agierende, der nicht wirklich wütend ist. Man kann Gefühle nicht nur unterdrücken, sondern auch vortäuschen. @KritikerderElche: Der Mitarbeiter könnte zum Schluss kommen, weil er den Chef gut kennt und von früheren Ereignissen weiß, dass hier wieder eine Situation vorliegt, die ihn ganz bestimmt wütend macht, dass er sich das aber, wie so oft, nicht anmerken lässt. Streng genommen umfasst "nobody" zwar auch den Chef selbst, aber so pedantisch wird selten gesprochen. "Nobody except himself" wäre korrekt.

Comment: @KritikerderElche: Lass es gut sein. Du befeuerst mit deinem sturen Beharren auf unhaltbaren Positionen nur eine Diskussion, die alle anderen schon seit Tagen nervt. Wo sind eigentlich die Moderatoren, die bei wesentlich konstruktiveren Diskussionen auch keine Hemmungen haben, sie in den Chat-Mistkübel zu entsorgen?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Guter Vorschlag, zum Ende der Diskussion zu kommen. Aber bitte nicht persönlich werden, Deine Wortwahl ist nicht gut.

Answer (score 8):

The difference is that the verb, *wüten*, has fallen almost completely out of use except in idioms, while the derived adjective, *wütend* (angry) is still common, indeed probably the most-used adjective to describe that state of mind.

As often happens in such cases, the meaning of the derived adjective has faded somewhat; *wüten* implies actually running around breaking stuff and hurting people, while *wütend* can be performed perfectly well just by displaying a red face and shouting a lot.

Comment: _wüten_ means to rampage, to riot or to cause havoc. It's still in use with storms or (violent) demonstrantions. A synonym would be toben.

Comment: I don't think *wüten* is that rare, at least according to the handy *Worthäufigkeit* data given by DWDS, but you're right that it's less common than *wütend*. I gather that in the first sentence the boss is just angry, and in the second the boss is having a real tantrum and throwing things, or at least he's mad enough to.

Answer (score 5):

These terms are completely different. *Wütend sein* is just description of mood (be angry), possibly connected to high blood pressure and some angry reactions when asked for something.

*Wüten* is always an action, possibly resulting from this mood. It is frequently used in connection with thunderstorms and ancient warriors on the battlefield. In office context it wouldnot be my choice of a verb, since it is at least means throwing papers around, shouting/cursing.

Comment: This does not address the main problem of the OP - that _wütend_ is a participle of _wüten_.

Comment: The words have a common root, *Wut*, and the meanings are related if not the same. But I take your point that *wütend sein* is considered a figure of speech while *wüten* is taken literally, at least when applied to people. It's been mentioned that *wüten* is used a lot with disasters, and you wouldn't say a fire is literally "raging" (from anger), but that seems to be a common expression in both English and German. So I guess both terms can be figurative but it different ways.

Comment: Die Einschränkung auf ancient warriors erscheint mir von Wunschdenken getrieben.

Answer (score 3):

They don't mean the same thing at all, and the reason is that while "wütend" ("angry") is etymologically a participle of "wüten" ("to rage"), it has functionally become an adjective sharing the same word root.

In modern language use, they have to be considered separate words with separate dictionary entries.  Consequently, this doesn't really constitute an exception from the rule since "wütend" is not being employed as a participle even though that is its origin story.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to tell because dictionaries often list the participle separately as an adjective even when it's meaning is basically the same as the root verb.

Answer (score 2):

This is more an extended comment than a profound answer.

Some of the previous answers claim that "wüten" is no longer in use except in the context of forces of nature or warrior hordes. I disagree although I admit that "wütend sein" is the standard expression to decribe feelings of anger. But if these negative feelings are very strong it may still be adequate to use the verb "wüten". Here are some examples from [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/w%C3%BCten):

1. Er sprang zornig auf und wütete.
2. Ich kann es nicht länger mit ansehen, wie Sie gegen sich selber wüten [Stephan Zweig, Amok, 327]
3. Der Wirt, der sich zunächst zurückgehalten hatte, wütete geradezu, wenn jemand vorschlug, Schluß zu machen. [Degenhardt, Franz Josef: Die Abholzung, Berlin: Aufbau-Taschenbuch-Verl. 1999 [1985], S. 24]
4. Die aber wüten nur um sich, weil sie verkaufen wollen. [konkret, 1980]
5. So wütet er vor allem gegen die, die an ihn wie er an sie gebunden ist. [Die Zeit, 28.05.2001, Nr. 22]

One can also use the combination "[herumwüten](https://www.dwds.de/wb/herumw%C3%BCten)". Examples:

1. [Er tobt, er wütet herum – er hat unsere Familie zerstört.](https://books.google.de/books?id=qpUDAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT33&lpg=PT33&dq=er+w%C3%BCtet+herum&source=bl&ots=kqo1vAPEZh&sig=ACfU3U2u-vOdG1K-omNGxdn-IFuoFMsxhQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf9faZ2Of3AhVGR_EDHYZvCSQQ6AF6BAgpEAM#v=onepage&q=er%20w%C3%BCtet%20herum&f=false)
2. [Er redet wirr und wütet herum, das ist eine Auswirkung der ganzen Drogen.](https://books.google.de/books?id=2pYnEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT469&lpg=PT469&dq=er+w%C3%BCtet+herum&source=bl&ots=KaXhKVgOCe&sig=ACfU3U2Q9feh59NeayZ-cRWq-fsWKyr1GQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf9faZ2Of3AhVGR_EDHYZvCSQQ6AF6BAgqEAM#v=onepage&q=er%20w%C3%BCtet%20herum&f=false)
3. [Er murmelt Unverständliches vor sich hin, wütet herum und befiehlt mir Arbeiten zu verrichten, die ich schon Tage zuvor erledigt habe.](https://books.google.de/books?id=wBVvAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT241&lpg=PT241&dq=er+w%C3%BCtet+herum&source=bl&ots=Gj2Osst6S3&sig=ACfU3U0RxY_dSuj9BjKldTbBNmKrboxcVA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf9faZ2Of3AhVGR_EDHYZvCSQQ6AF6BAgoEAM#v=onepage&q=er%20w%C3%BCtet%20herum&f=false)
4. [Das Kind wird von seinen Emotionen überwältigt – es wütet.](https://www.babyartikel.de/magazin/wutanfall-beim-kleinkind-so-reagierst-du-richtig)
5. [Der Chef patrouilliert zwischen den Schreibtischen und nähert sich einer Mitarbeiterin, die vor Nervosität die Bleistiftspitze abbricht. Vom Geräusch provoziert, rastet er völlig aus, wütet herum und droht sogar mit Rausschmiss. Wer einen Choleriker zum Chef hat, kann sich eben keine Fehler leisten.](https://kuvb.de/presse/presse-archiv/presse-archiv-im-detail/info/austicken-ist-so-neunziger/?tx_contrast=80&cHash=4c6dee36fd9d9f0502b699011a845f47)

Comment: I agree that *wüten* is used quite a bit while not applied to disasters. But it is often used figuratively in that way. Both English and German have raging fires and raging storms, but think a raging plague sounds very odd in English, apparently not in German. Thanks for finding these examples; apparently *wüten* does not necessarily mean you're actually throwing things, but it still means you're more upset than just *wütend*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in meaning.

While etymologically the adjective (not participle!) *wütend* was once derived from the verb *wüten* and their meanings still have a little bit to do with each other, they are for all intents and purposes separate words in modern German. In fact, you can put *wüten* and *wütend* into the same sentence and they would each add a slightly different nuance to the final product:

> Der wütende Chef wütet in seinem Büro.

The *wütend* tells us that his primary emotion is anger while the *wütet* tells us that his actions are raging, smashing things, etc. The difference becomes more obvious (in my opinion), if we exchange either word for something similar and see what comes out:

> Der enttäuschte Chef wütet in seinem Büro.

Here, the action is the same but the root cause is disappointment rather than rage (compare ‘I’m not angry, just disappointed.’).

> Der wütende Chef brüllt in seinem Büro.

In this case, the boss is still angry but he is voicing his anger by yelling rather than by smashing objects.

---

All of the above is very different from a true participle which is understood as a participle in modern German, e.g. *bellend*.

> Der Hund bellt.
> Der bellende Hund

> *Der Hund ist bellend.

The final one is not considered idiomatic German, but the first two convey exactly the same meaning.

(The last one might be found in meme speak in German internet communities; e.g. I have read ‘Ich bin weinend’ by native Germans multiple times on Twitter but the phrasing is still not considered idiomatic standard German.)

Comment: "Der Hund ist bellend" would be a poor translation from English, but not German IMHO.

Comment: @U.Windl Yes, that is exactly what I said. However note that native Germans sometimes [post stuff like this on Twitter for memes](https://twitter.com/aminachu/status/1356612859451633672).

Answer (score 0):

Not a good linguistic explanation, but I think the major difference is that
"wütend sein" is the state of the person (mostly), while "wüten" typically refers to actions of the person (typically affecting other persons or things, like throwing things around).
https://german.stackexchange.com/a/70604/39153 says similar.
Probably the second one is more specific than the first one; while the boss is "wütend" you might try to avoid him, but when the boss is "wüten"ing, it's most likely too late when the action is against you.